# How to convert a stem and leaf plot into a data set in R?

Tags: r, csv

The stem and leaf plot that I need to convert is given below-

```
24|9
23|
22|1
21|7
20|2, 2, 5, 5, 6, 9, 9, 9
19|0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 8
18|0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 9, 9, 9
17|1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9
16|0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8
15|0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9
14|0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9
13|0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9
12|1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9
11|0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 9, 9
10|0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8
9|0, 0, 9
8|6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different approach. Using @MrFlick's `stem` and `rows` objects:

```
rows <- strsplit(stem,"\n")[[1]]
rows.lst <- strsplit(rows,"\\|")
tens <- as.numeric(sapply(rows.lst, "[", 1)) * 10
ones <- sapply(strsplit(sapply(rows.lst, "[", 2), ","), as.numeric)
vals <- unlist(mapply("+", tens, ones))
vals <- vals[!is.na(vals)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's maybe one way. If your data looks like this

```
stem <- "24|9
23|
22|1
21|7
20|2, 2, 5, 5, 6, 9, 9, 9
19|0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 8
18|0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 9, 9, 9
17|1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9
16|0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8
15|0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9
14|0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9
13|0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9
12|1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9
11|0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 9, 9
10|0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8
9|0, 0, 9
8|6"
```

Then we can split up the rows and for each row we split by the pipe. Then we split the right side by commas and join each of those values to the value to the left of the pipe.

```
rows <- strsplit(stem,"\n")[[1]]
values <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(rows,"\\|"), function(x) {
  end_digits <- strsplit(x[2], ", ")[[1]]
  if (!all(is.na(end_digits))) {
    paste0(x[1], end_digits)
  } else {
    NULL
  }
}
))
```

This will return character values, but you could convert to numeric with

```
as.numeric(values)
```